# Create a pivot table from 2 fact tables

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I have three tables fetched from an SQL DB:

**[T1] changes:** *CR Number is the primary key.*

```
CR Number | Planned Start | Planned End | Category
```

**[T2] changes_impacted_clients:** *No primary key*

```
CR Number | Impacted Client
```

**[T3] clients:** *Client ID is the primary key.*

```
Client ID | Status
```

I created a 1-to-many relationship between:

- changes[CR Number] and changes_impacted_clients[CR Number]
- clients[Client ID] and changes_impacted_clients[Impacted Client]

**Desired Results:**

I would like to create a Pivot Table to list the following columns:

```
CR Number | Planned Start | Planned End | Impacted Client
```

I want each row to the list of clients related to each CR Number. The pivot keeps repeating the records in the Impacted Clients at each row not matter they are related to the CR Number or not.

Comment: "not giving me the correct results" - what exactly does this mean?

Comment: Thank you @RADO I edited my question to provide more clarity of what I expect from my table.

Comment: Replace Impacted Client with Client ID from T3. You might also want to drop a DAX measure into this pivot to bring T1 and T3 together, for example: COUNTROWS(T2)

Comment: Client ID didn't work. I did it with the COUNTROWS(T2) and had to hide the column of this measure in the pivot. Thank you! I still think there is another way to do this.

Comment: There is no other way; it actually works exactly as intended. When you used "Impacted Client", it's a mistake because you were trying to filter T1 by T2, which is impossible (because filters always flow from 1 to Many, not the other way around). When you use Client_ID, it needs to know how it's related to T1, and the only way to do it is to bring information from T2 (which is the only table that contains information about T1 and T2 relations). Also, you don't need COUNTROWS measure - it's just an example. Any measure that involves T2 will do.